# my xpath is good, but i've got nothing with scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I try to scrap one page with scrapy. I found the xpath with FireXpath (a firefox plugin), and it seem good. But with Scrapy, I've got no result.

My python program look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from datetime import datetime
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider

class robtex(BaseSpider):
    # Crawling Start
    CrawlSpider.started_on = datetime.now()
    # CrawlSpider
    name = 'robtex'

    DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3
    start_urls = [ "https://www.whois.com/en/advisory/dns/com/stackoverflow/whois.html"]


    def parse(self, response):
        # Selector
        sel = Selector(response)
        print sel.xpath(".//*[@id='datawhois']/div[2]/table[3]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/a/text()").extract()
```

How to fixe it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to remove `tbody` from the XPath expression:

```
.//*[@id='datawhois']/div[2]/table[3]/tr[3]/td[2]/a/text()
```

Demo:

```
$ scrapy shell https://www.robtex.com/en/advisory/dns/com/stackoverflow/whois.html
In [1]: response.xpath(".//*[@id='datawhois']/div[2]/table[3]/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/a/text()").extract()
Out[1]: []

In [2]: response.xpath(".//*[@id='datawhois']/div[2]/table[3]/tr[3]/td[2]/a/text()").extract()
Out[2]: [u'STACKOVERFLOW.COM']
```

Comment: I'm facing simillar problem and whant to understand, why remove tbody make it works?

Comment: @RicardoSilva `tbody` as well as `thead` and other things are something that a browser would usually insert..scrapy is not a browser..

Comment: is there any way to recognize if <tbody> and <thead> really exists in code? Or the only way is trial and error?

Comment: @RicardoSilva you don't have to use xpath expressions like in this topic - actually, these kind of expressions are not quite reliable generally. Just skip tbody or theads..for example: `//table[@id="myid"]//tr` would match all rows..hope you got the idea.